# RxJs How to Observe object property change

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, rxjs, observable

I'm running into an issue. I have a client that instantiates that has a ready Boolean property. I want to wait until it switches to true then resolve a promise. I tried a lot of different ways including while loop that just blocks the thread completely without checking for updates.

Here's that attempt

```
var startClient = function() { return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
          var client = CreateClient();
          while(!client.ready) {}
          resolve(client);
     });
};
```

My question is: Is there a way to use RxJs to help.. Maybe emit and event if the ready property is changed? Below is more pseudo code for what I'm trying to do.

```
var startClient = function() { return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
          var client = CreateClient();
          var emitter = Observable.watch(client, 'ready');
          emitter.on('ready', function(result) { 
               if(result) resolve(client);
          });
};
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, you could overwrite the `ready` property on the client to trap assignments to it, as follows:

```
// Check if the ready flag is already set.
if (client.ready) return resolve(client);

let _ready;
Object.defineProperty(client, 'ready', {

  // Trap an assignment and resolve if true.
  set(b) { _ready = b; if (b) resolve(client); },

  // Politely provider a getter in case someone else is trying to access it.
  get()  { return _ready; }

});
```

This won't work if the property is not configurable, or the object is frozen, etc.

Comment: Thank you, this worked out great and allowed me to get rid of a module dependency.